# Convert string to date in mm-yyyy format in php

Tags: php

I have $year and $month as two variables. I want to convert them into date so that I can insert it into mysql table. I just want to store mm-yyyy in mysql.Is it possible in php?

Comment: "yes it is possible" (That entirely answers your question)

Comment: Can't you just do <?php $date = $month.'-'.$year; ?> or am I missing something?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: try this man SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2012-07-00 00:00:00');

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "$year-$month-01";
```

If you plan on storing it in a real 'date' field, you must have a day of the month too.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL displays DATE values in ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ format.

So if you want it as a DATE, you have to put a day in your date like : `$date = "$year-$month-$day"`.

If you don't want it as a DATE, you can store it as a 'MM-YYYY' like that : `$date = "$month-$year"`.

After, you just have to make your MYSQL Query and it will work.